# FB comment "load 10 more comments" button click call application window resize event not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-comments, fbml

I am using "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" javascript SDK to load comment in my application. 
Now my issue is that I am not able to track load more click event inside comment iframe. I need to track functionality to set parent div height as per the comments div height which is loaded after clicking on the load more button event.

Comment: Comments appear in iframe and you cannot bind any events to the elements in iframe, your best bet is to use overflow auto in that case

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to call the resize event as well on load more click because of that my parent div height is not getting changed.

Comment: I used "FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function (response) {})" function to set height of parent div after loading comment but afte that when I am trying to load other comments through loadmore then can't find any event so based on that I can change parent div height.

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Comment: There is no event for this, and you can not add your own event handler, because all of this happens inside a 3rd-party iframe that you have no access to.

Comment: Checking the example in the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/, the iframe seems to adapt its own size already, when more comments are loaded. So unless you built your layout in a way that prevents the height change of the iframe to affect the rest of your layout automatically, there should be no need to fix anything in that regard in the first place …?

Comment: Please find my code on "https://jsfiddle.net/vb4xgcmo/". It won't work directly but you can copy and paste the same code and keep in the HTML page and run that.

Comment: Of course it can’t grow by itself as usual, if you lock it into a container element with a fixed height of 300px. I guess specifying a min-height instead should probably solve your problem without trying to handle resizing on your own …

Comment: It is just a sample but in my live application, I have to set a height of the parent element to fix so need a solution for this because window.resize() not working on click of load more button.

Comment: Well I guess you could try and periodically check the actual height of the iframe element (assuming it will still try and auto-size itself in that situation), and then adapt the height of your container element accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with different solutions and found one working sample using the modified code available on "https://jsfiddle.net/vb4xgcmo/".

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.Event.subscribe( 'xfbml.render', function ( response ) {
                if ( $( '.fb-comments' ).length > 0 ) {
                    if ( $( '.fb-comments iframe' ).length > 0 ) {
                        iframeClickTracking( $( '.fb-comments iframe' ) );
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
        function iframeClickTracking( elm ) {
            elm.bind( 'mouseover', function () {
                console.log( 'in' );
                onIframeHeightChange( elm, function () {
                    $( '#section_1' ).css( 'height', $( '#fbv' ).height() );
                } );

            } );
            elm.bind( 'mouseout', function () {
                // If they leave the ad, then they aren't going to click. Kill the run event for resize.
                setTimeout( function () {
                    if ( elm.onIframeHeightChange ) {
                        $( '#section_1' ).css( 'height', $( '#fbv' ).height() );
                        clearTimeout( elm.onIframeHeightChange );
                    }
                }, 1000 );
            } );
        }

        function onIframeHeightChange( elm, callback ) {
            var lastHeight = elm.height(), newHeight;
            (function run() {
                newHeight = elm.height();
                if ( lastHeight != newHeight ) {
                    callback();
                }
                lastHeight = newHeight;
                if ( elm.onIframeHeightChange ) {
                    clearTimeout( elm.onIframeHeightChange );
                }
                elm.onIframeHeightChange = setTimeout( run, 1000 );
            })();
        }
```

Comment: You can find updated code on "https://jsfiddle.net/29ns6a0L/" and old code in above given URL.